# Is there any BigDecimal class for C?

Tags: c, bigdecimal

I looked all over the internet and I can't seem to find one.

There is something similar in Java, but I need to use C (preferably something I can use locally). Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798777/is-there-a-c-equivalent-to-javas-bigdecimal/4798817#4798817 question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any solid large integer implementations in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191002/are-there-any-solid-large-integer-implementations-in-c)

Comment: Since there is no such thing as a "class" in C, no, no there is not.

Comment: I did, just trollin' :D.  Still, an odd phrase to use when discussing C.

Comment: @JerryCoffin BigDecimal is not a "large integer", silly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy of my answer:

If you need to do operations with HUGE decimal values I would suggest you to use http://gmplib.org/ library. I've used it a lot with C and C++.